# Application needs to be running for dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name to work?

Tags: unix, glib, dbus

Can i call dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name without the application that implements the D-Bus method to be up and running ?
I'm not sure if it is good practice to do so, or if is usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer, I'd like to point out that **[DBus-GLib is deprecated](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings)**.  However, the answer applies to [g_dbus_proxy_new](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusProxy.html#g-dbus-proxy-new) (which is basically the replacement for [dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/dbus-glib-DBusGProxy.html#dbus-g-proxy-new-for-name)) as well.

Yes.  The the [dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/dbus-glib-DBusGProxy.html#dbus-g-proxy-new-for-name) talks about how the owner can change over time, though it doesn't explicitly mention the case of when there is no owner at the time of the call (original emphasis):

> THE NAME OWNER MAY CHANGE OVER TIME, for example between two different method calls, unless the name is a unique name. If you need a fixed owner, you need to request the current owner and bind a proxy to its unique name rather than to the generic name; see dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name_owner().

It's actually very common to use this with D-Bus activation.  Check out the "Client Implementation" section of [Raphaël Slinckx' DBus Activation Tutorial](http://raphael.slinckx.net/blog/documents/dbus-tutorial).  It includes this snippet (pay attention to the comments):

```
/* This won't trigger activation! */
proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name (connection,
        "org.gnome.ServiceName",
        "/org/gnome/ServiceName",
        "org.gnome.ServiceName");

/* The method call will trigger activation, more on that later */
if (!org_gnome_ServiceName_echo_string (proxy, "The string we want echo-ed", &result, &error))
{
    /* Method failed, the GError is set, let's warn everyone */
    g_warning ("Woops remote method failed: %s", error->message);
    g_error_free (error);
    return;
}
```

D-Bus activation doesn't even get triggered until after a method is called, so obviously the name doesn't necessarily exist before then.